# How to display random 10 authors with their avatars?

Tags: wordpress

I am using code below, to display all author's avatars of blog on my wordpress webpage. However, I would like to display 10 random avatars,  not all od them. Is there any way to do without using some plugin?

```
$blogusers = get_users_of_blog();
if ($blogusers) {
    foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
        $user = get_userdata($bloguser->user_id);
        echo get_avatar( $user->ID, 70 ); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_users_of_blog` is deprecated. Use `get_users` instead:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users

Using `get_users` alone, you cannot get random users, but you can use the `pre_user_query` action to update the `ORDER BY` clause in the SQL:

```
// Update the query to order by random
function randomize_users(&$query) {
    $query->query_orderby = "ORDER BY RAND()";
}

// Attach the function to the pre_user_query hook
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'randomize_users' );

// Get the users
$users = get_users(array(
    'blog_id' => get_current_blog_id(),
    'number' => 10
));

// Remove the action so future queries won't be affected
remove_action( 'pre_user_query', 'randomize_users' );
```

Source: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20606